# How to Fix Errors for ActivityFeeds.UI.js?

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

Every now and then I get an error in CRM 2015 online:

The error occurs in https://server.crm.dynamics.com/%7B635987670810004466%7D/WebResources/msdyn_/ActivityFeeds.UI.js?ver=1428721370

[image]

If I Look at the $$t_7 variable, all properties are null, except for _disposed, which is true.

I'm not sure what else I can do since it's not a script I can edit.

Thoughts?

Comment: I freaking hate these errors.

Answer (score 0):

The only real way you could accomplish this that I can think of would be to wait for the script to load, and then overwrite the problematic function with an identical copy except the body of the function is wrapped in a try catch.  If the function uses closures, you'd have to replace the functions parent, and if the parent has closures, you'd have to replace the parent of that too, etc (potentially all the way up to the whole file). It could be a major PITA because there might be event handlers you'd have to deal with, but it should be doable.  That assumes your code could run before the error occurs, though, which may not be possible.

Another option would be to find the error reporting mechanism and see if you can modify it to remove the activity feed errors, which would effectively silence the reporting (assuming that is your end goal).

Comment: So I'm hearing to contact MS and suck it up, because it ain't getting fixed.  Also wondering why I'm the only one with this problem...

Comment: You got it! I see this regularly because I always have error reporting turned on. I'm guessing most people turn it off, or maybe it's off by default? This is one of the only errors I ever actually submit to MS...just for my own personal satisfaction.

Comment: We're upgrading to 2016, I think I'll hope that fixes it.

Comment: We were still getting it on 2016 last month iirc. :(

Comment: Dang you!  Crushing my dreams!